# MVC3 DropDownListFor SelectedItem not being selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

In my controller I have the following (code omitted for brevity):

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
    {
        vw_user u = _respository.getProfile(id);

        var model = new UserProfileEditViewModel
        {
            SL_collegeid = new SelectList(_respository.getColleges(u.State), "id", "college1", u.id)

        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

Now when I debug the model right before the return it is showing that the particular college (u.id) is selected in the SelectList (SL_collegeid).  However, when the page loads the selected item is not selected.

Here is the code for cshtml:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.SL_collegeid, Model.SL_collegeid)
```

Could some one please help me out with this?

Thank you in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did the view in question have nothing selected when the controller method got called? If so, the model doesn't overwrite what is in ModelState dictionary-- so even if you change the model property that is the backing field for the view, the originally posted data will trump it. Again, if that's the case, you can get around it by not using the html helpers and manually setting the values in HTML using Razor syntax.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I am very new to MVC/Razor. Having said that I would equate to what this action is doing as a page_load event. However, when I changed the ddl in question to @Html.DropDownList("collegeid",Model.SL_collegeid) it worked as expected. So I guess my question is what was wrong with the DropDownListFor?

Comment: @Chris - Ah, I think I misunderstood your original question. In the DropDownListFor method, the first argument "model.SL_collegeid" is where in the model the selected item from the list will be bound to, while the second "Model.SL_collegeid" is the select item list itself. In the plain DropDownList, the first argument is the control name, and the second is the list name. When you used the DropDownListFor, what type was your "model.SL_collegeid"? Is that the collection, or a string/int property to catch the selected id?

Comment: the model.SL_collegeid is the collection.  So I guess I would want add the collegeid from the profile to the model and then try to catch it that way? So the code would look like @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.id, Model.SL_collegeid  -- does not work btw.  I really need to get a handle on this lambda thing.

Comment: @Chris - In the expression, @Html.DropDownListFor(m => ... ), the "m" refers to the strongly typed Model for the view. So if your model did have an Id, and that Id was a string (since an HTML select Id and Value are both string), then you could bind to it like that. Although I do think that the model binding will do the cast for you if you bind it to an int.

Comment: I got it....  @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.SL_collegeid.SelectedValue, Model.SL_collegeid) works and now that I have the answer it makes sense.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You must return correct object in statement :

```
return view(yourObj);
```

Or you can also try :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.SL_collegeid,new SelectList(Model.YourDropDownList as System.Collections.IEnumerable,model.SL_collegeid ))
```